# C# XmlDocument.LoadXml And Wildcards

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an asp.net application and I'm using C#. I want to use the XmlDocument.LoadXml() method to read from an .xml file. However, the xml file will not always have the same name so I wanted to pass into the LoadXml() method the path to the file and then read any .xml files that are inside. So, something like this LoadXml(C:\Docs*.xml). It doesn't work for me. Is there another way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate out the "loading XML from a file" from "picking which file to load". The two are unrelated concepts. (Although I would point out that [`XmlDocument.LoadXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) takes raw XML as a string, *not* a filename. I think you want [`XmlDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx).)

What do you want to happen if there's more than one XML document in `c:\Docs`? `XmlDocument` can only load one of them.

Use [`Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Docs", "*.xml")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) to get the list of matching files in the directory. What you should do if there's more than one of them (or none) is up to you.

Comment: Hey thanks, there should only be one in the directory and it gets overwritten.

Comment: Then I would make that very explicit in the code - if there isn't exactly one appropriate file, you should probably throw an exception. Glad it helped though.